# Unexpected token, expected "," (88:1) (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to find where i forget to put the (,) .... is says line 88

I could not fit the hole thing on the code ctrl+k option

```
 86 |     </Container>
  87 |     );
> 88 | };
```

[This is the hole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXUSg.png)

Comment: Forgot to close `useEffect` - check line 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review your `useEffect` function. You forget to close your `useEffect` with curly bracket and round bracket

here the code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
       const taskFromServer = await fetchUsers()
       settasks(tasksFromServer);
    }
})
```

Comment: okay i get now thank you.. i do not know why it was showing 88 line

Comment: Your welcome. It's becouse your app's assume you close `useEffect function` on line 88